# Can't get ivar from other class

Tags: objective-c, macos, properties

I normally don't stumble on these things, but I'm trying to put or even fetch an ivar in another class. I tried setting the variable as strong also, but I always get a null value.

#### NewView.h

```
@interface NewView : NSView <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSString *__setValue;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *setValue;
- (IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender;
@end
```

#### NewView.m

```
#import "NewView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation NewView 
@synthesize value;
@synthesize setValue;

- (IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender {

     /* Also Tried
     AppDelegate *get = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
     setValue = get.appDelegateString;
     */

    NSLog(@"setValue: %@",setValue); // always returns NULL
}
@end
```

#### AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString *__appDelegateString;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *appDelegateString;
-(IBAction)displayString:(id)sender;
@end
```

#### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NewView.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize appDelegateString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self displayString:nil];
}

-(IBAction)displayString:(id)sender {
    appDelegateString = @"TEST";
    NSLog(@"appDelegateString: %@", appDelegateString);
    [self putString];
}

- (void)putString {
    NewView *put = [[NewView alloc] init];
    put.setValue = appDelegateString;
}
@end
```

NSLog:

```
appDelegateString: TEST
setValue: (null)
```

Do I need to do something special to get the ivar across classes?

Comment: `@synthesize` has been unnecessarily for a long time.  `IBOutlet` is extraordinarily strange to see on a `NSString` property.  `awakeFromNib` is being fired before your `put.value = `... line is fired.

Comment: Even if I don't check for the value in `awake from nib`, but elsewhere it's still null.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I hesitated for anything more strange, because I wasn't sure if maybe you actually could make use of `IBOutlet` here.  I know that `IB_Inspectable` would be potentially useful here, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`awakeFromNib` is being called before you set the `value` property.

If you change your `putNumber` method to the following:

```
- (void)putNumber {
    NewView *put = [[NewView alloc] init];
    put.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
    NSLog(@"value: %@", put.value);
}
```

it should appropriately print the value.

If you check the `.value` property else where and it returns `NULL`, it's almost certainly because you're checking a different instance of your `NewView` class, one for which the `value` property hasn't been set.

Comment: That prints it in AppDelegate, but I'm trying to print it from NewView.

Comment: Then you need to print it after you set it.

Comment: How can I call `value` from class `NewView`? Setting it in `AppDelegate` with `put.value` works, but if I try and `NSLog(@"value: %@",value);` in `NewView` even after setting it in `AppDelegate` I still get `NULL`. If you can please tell me why it's doing that I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure you are printing it after you set it?

Comment: Yes. The thing that I figured out what I'm actually doing (which is wrong) is creating another instance of AppDelegate, so that's why it's not returning anything. Using `NSSharedApplication` solves the issue in the case of `AppDelegate`, although I was hoping to use this on other classes as well. For instance getting a variable from one NSView to another.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many things wrong with the above code for me to pinpoint the exact point of failure so here's a list of tips to improve the situation:

1. Make your life easier and start using `@property` declarations
   instead of ivars and `@synthesize`.
2. Your `NSString` properties need to be `strong`, not `weak`. Think of them as balloons, do you want to tie a string to that balloon or just let it float away. If you let it float away and then end up needing it later, you're screwed.
3. Don't name your ivar (or your properties) with the prefix `set`, you'll just end up confusing yourself because your properties auto-synthesize with that prefix by default. Start with something harmless like `myString`, which will auto-synthesize into the getter/setter: `-(NSString *)myString` and `-(void)setMyString:(NSString *)myString`
4. IBOutlet for NSString is totally useless.
5. Your ivars are prefixed with `__` which is also unnecessary for your situation and problematic. See #1

Comment: I don't get any errors, so there wasn't any indicator that it was wrong. I had to use  `__` because of the weak references. Even when I tried using `strong` though I got a nuill returned value. Why is `IBOutlet` useless for `NSString`?

Comment: IBOutlet is a means of connecting an interface builder (IB) element like a label, button or image view to a property in your code. Since an NSString is not a UI element that you place in IB, it is silly to make it an IBOutlet.

Comment: If you use `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;` you're all set for storing your string. No need for an ivar, no need for @synthesize. You can drop all that crap until you have a damn good reason to use them on something more complicated. Continue to update your code and look for other reasons why it isn't working after that.